# jQuery does not work with infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have just made a new wordpress theme and I am using the following script to get an accordion-like effect.

```
( function( $ ) {
    var $ele = $('.entry-content').hide(); 
    $(".entry-header").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var $ele1 = $(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideToggle('fast');
        $ele.not($ele1).slideUp(); 
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

I just activated jetpack's [infinite scroll](https://jetpack.com/support/infinite-scroll/). The jquery script does not work on newly loaded content added by infinite scroll. My guess is that the script has to be reloaded, or at least triggered, whenever new content is added by infinite scroll. I have searched the web this whole day without finding any solution. Any help here would be appreciated.

I have enqueued my .js in my functions.php like this:

```
function journial() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'journial', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/journial.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'journial' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger an event after posts are appended. To make use of this event, simply catch the post-load event when it fires on document.body:

```js
(function($){ //wait until dom has loaded 

  function initAccordion(){ // first, prepare your function 
    var $ele = $('.entry-content').hide();
    $(".entry-header").unbind('click').click(function(e) { // bind click event handler 
      e.preventDefault();
      var $ele1 = $(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideToggle('fast');
      $ele.not($ele1).slideUp();
    }); 
  } 

  initAccordion(); // second, run the function the first time page loads 
  
  $(document.body).on('post-load', function(){// third, setup event handeler 
  initAccordion(); //run the funtion again after new content is loaded 
  }); 

} )(jQuery);
```

Comment: That did not work. Is the `post-load` specific to infinite scroll or was it just an example?

Comment: It's specific to Jetpack. I just pulled the code from the very bottom of this page... https://jetpack.com/support/infinite-scroll/.  Are you getting errors?

Comment: I also read the article but it did not say where I am supposed to put this code. In my jQuery script? In my functions.php or in the ajax.php...

Comment: Your own "functions.js" (or whatever you've named it) should be loaded via functions.php using wp_enqueue_script();. This way you can specify dependencies like jQuery, Jetpack, and other libraries you're dependent on. Wordpress will load scripts in the proper order if you've listed the dependencies. Have you loaded your scripts like this? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: I have enqueued my script in my functions.php, yes. See my updated question above.

Comment: It appears you're loading your scripts in your footer. That boolean at the end of wp_enqueue_scripts() should probably be set to false if you are using Jetpack's "scroll" option as opposed to "click". The latter will load your wordpress footer. The former will not, thus, your scripts should be in your head.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111902/discussion-between-arete-and-justin-mckee).

Comment: I updated answer to include your code with the 'post-load' event handler